# how can i install itertools module in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-requests

pip install itertools
it shows
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement itertools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for itertools

Comment: The itertools module is built in, you do not need to install it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to install itertools. Simply import it by:

```py
import itertools
```